# Custom datastructure: Dictionary of dictionaries with cumulative value

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

#### Context

I'm working on a python script that manipulates statistics provided by Google relatively to installed apps from the Play Store.

In particular, I'm recording, for every app, the amount of installations per month, per country. Given that Google provides these informations via a csv file with a row per day per country, I had to build a custom data structure that stores the values while parsing all the rows of all the lines.

#### So far

I've come up with a dictionary of dictionaries. The keys of the first level dictionary are the months (`datetime` objects). The values are dictionaries which keys are the countries, and the values are the cumulative amount of installations for the corresponding country, for the corresponding month.

This gives me a dictionary with the structure `{Month : {Country : amount_of_installs} }`

This allows me to build the following function to progressively fill my dictionary:

```
def addNewValue(dictionary, month, country, valueToAdd):
    if month in dictionary:
        if country in dictionary[month]:
            dictionary[month][country] += valueToAdd
        else:
            dictionary[month][country] = valueToAdd
    else:
        dictionary[month] = {country: valueToAdd}
```

#### Question

While this is a *working solution*, it feels like a serious non-optimal hack. Therefore, and for the sake of education, I'm wondering if there's another, better solution for such a task. Maybe another more optimal data structure that I'm not aware of, an existing class that manages to do this already, in a better manner.

That's it, thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you use a nested [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd

dictionary = dd(lambda: dd(int))
```

If you pass said data structure to your function, the function can simply be:

```
def addNewValue(dictionary, month, country, valueToAdd):
    dictionary[month][country] += valueToAdd
```